# Unfocused colour of TextField

Tags: hyperref, forms

I'm trying to get the colour of an unfocused TextField to be the same as when it is focused.
Is there a way to do this? Alternatively is there a way to make it transparent when it isn't focused?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=testfield, backgroundcolor=1 0 0, bordercolor=1 0 0, multiline, width=30em, height=10em, borderwidth=0]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as always don't show only a snippet but show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Your code cannot compile as it is missing `\begin{Form}` or `\end{Form}` is not required. Help people to help you by creating a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), this link explains in-depth what is best practice. There is more then likely a solution to your question but it helps a lot if people can just copy and paste code and then trial/debug etc.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Some PDF viewers by default overlay inactive text fields with a certain color (typically a light transparent violet). I went through the [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf) where I found the methods `runtimeHighlight` and `runtimeHighlightColor` that allow you to disable and set the highlighting color of form fields.

So, you can use JS flavoured styling of a `\TextField` setting the value of its `format` option to `app.runtimeHighlight = false;` which will remove the highlighting of text fields altogether. It is sufficient to set this only for the first `\TextField` in your document since this is a document-wide setting. Note that this only works reliably using Acrobat Reader for displaying the PDF. Other PDF viewers may not adhere to these settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[
        name=testfield, 
        backgroundcolor=1 0 0, 
        bordercolor=1 0 0, 
        multiline, 
        width=30em, 
        height=10em, 
        borderwidth=0, 
        format={app.runtimeHighlight = false;}
    ]{}
    
    % you only need to set this for the first text field, as it sets an document-wide setting
    \bigskip
    \TextField[
        name=testfield2, 
        backgroundcolor=1 0 0, 
        bordercolor=1 0 0, 
        multiline, 
        width=30em, 
        height=10em, 
        borderwidth=0
    ]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @hmiddeldorp I hope this could help you solving your problem. I am always happy to get some sort of reply.